# Htaccess Non-www to www POST issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I using followin code to redirect Non-WWW to WWW url
It's work.
But when i send POST data without www it's not work

My Htaccess  code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My post form code (with "www" , it's Work) :

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
</form>
```

My post form code (without "www" , does not Work,just redirect to index.php) :

```
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
</form>
```

Please Assist
Important :
When i adding below code to htaccess it's work

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Redirects for POST requests are tricky; check out the notes under the various HTTP 30x status codes in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: http://www.example.com and http://www.example.com/index.php are not the same??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And if you want use this: <form action="/" method="post"> I think is better

Comment: sorry.Does not work!can i add 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
to my code?It's wrong way?

Comment: Have you a virtualhost to www.example.com?

Comment: It's not on local.it's real server :)